# Getting the Second Lowest Value from a Range

Tags: excel

My input range is `AC38:BH38` which contains either a value or is empty.
There is also a range, `$AC$58:$BH$58`, which contains a value of `"Y"` or is also empty.

If a cell within the range `$AC$58:$BH$58` contains the value `"Y"`, then the corresponding cell within row 38 is not empty. I want the value within that cell only if its value is greater than 0.

The answers required are (formatted as Answer#_ = ):

1. Value of the 'Last cell' (Right hand side) of the input range AC38:BH38 meeting the above 2 conditions.
2. Value of the 1 cell left of the cell that satisfies Answer #1 if it also satisfies the initial conditions.
3. Value of the 2 cell LEFT to the above cell(Answer #1) provided it also meets the above conditions.
4. Value of the 3 cell LEFT to the above cell(Answer #1) provided it also meets the above conditions.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question. It's has a bad tone and isn't clear. Also I think we need more information here. Do you only want 4 "answers" to your question? Or do you want them for the entire range? What have you already attempted? You can't just ask for a solution without showing us what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do for the rightmost cell is enter this formula:

```
=IF(AND($BH$58="Y",$BH$38 > 0),TRUE,"")
```

And then starting with column `AC` take this:

```
=IF(AND(<your answer cell>=TRUE, AC$58="Y", AC$38 > 0),TRUE,"")
```

Make sure to apply it along the row until you get to the formula entered above

Comment: BradyK, editing the question's tone was okay.  But your formula seems to be going in a wrong direction...I need the formula for the WHOLE RANGE to find the Answers#1,2,3 & 4.

Comment: Do you only want the right most 4 or all? The formula can be applied for any cells... direction does not matter

Comment: Okay I suggest you edit the question to express this. It wasn't clear originally. I will work on it.

Comment: Edited question is crystal clear.  I want 4 answers from the entire range of AC38:BH38 in output cells, say, CA38, CB38, CC38 & CD38.  The formula should check all the cells of AC38:BH38 to ascertain which cell/(s) qualifies (a cell qualifies if it meets the above 2 conditions) & then give the answers as per the 4 types of requirements. 2 conditions: Value of the cell (in AC38:BH38) MUST BE>0; the corresponding cell in $AC$58:$BH$58 MUST CONTAIN the value "Y". Ex: AC38=777 & AC58=Y QUALIFIES; AD38=999 & AD58="" DOES NOT QUALIFIES

Answer (score -1):

use the `small` function. e.g.:

```
=small(range, 2)
```

this will give you the 2nd lowest value in a range. the other details are easy to add in.